# React Native Text Input fixed text

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I want to add something like a Hint, on the textInput, as in java using android studio, in react native is it possible to do this? I know you have the option to add a Value, defaultValue and the placeholder, but they don't work like hint.

Tanks!

Comment: create a custom box with hint value & when the user press on the text-input (using onFocus in react native text-input) set visibility of that hint box to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [placeholder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#placeholder) props

```
<TextInput 
  placeholder="Input email"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, it's called **placeholder**, Here is an example from [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input).:

```
<TextInput
      style={{height: 40}}
      placeholder="Type here to translate!"
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
      value={this.state.text}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is to add a the `placeholder` prop.

```
<TextInput 
...//otherprops
 placeholder="enter your hint here"
/>
```

I highly suggest you to read more about `TextInput` in React Native docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput)